# Returning variables from Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm looking at using a simple, currently ugly, GUI built with Tkinter to attain two variables from the user. Namely a file path and a choice from a dropdown (OptionMenu).

The variables selected will be used later in the Python script, which is where I'm running into difficulty. Put simply, how to asign the users choices to the variables: Carrier, Path.

Please see below for sample code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def Choose_Path():
    Tk().withdraw()
    return askopenfilename()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.configure(background='#A2B5CD')

C_Label = Label(root, text='Carrier Choice:', bg='#A2B5CD', fg='black',font=('Calibri', 12))
C_Label.grid(row=0,sticky=W, padx =10)
I_Label = Label(root, text='Invoice Path:', bg='#A2B5CD', fg='black',font=('Calibri', 12))
I_Label.grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx =10)


var = StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose Carrier...')
option = OptionMenu(root, var, 'DHL','DPD','DX','Fedex','Geodis','Hermes','WN Direct')
option.config(relief=RAISED, highlightbackground='#A2B5CD')
option.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W, pady = 10)

browser = Button(root, text = 'Browse Invoice...', command=Choose_Path)
browser.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)


Button(root, text='Accept and Close').grid(column=1, sticky=S)

root.mainloop()
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a combination of your feedback and a little more playing around with an extra function, I now seem to be getting the results that I need. See below for what it looks like now.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
path = []

def Choose_Path():
    Tk().withdraw()
    path.append(askopenfilename())

def CloseGUI():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.configure(background='#A2B5CD')

C_Label = Label(root, text='Carrier Choice:', bg='#A2B5CD', fg='black',font=('Calibri', 12))
C_Label.grid(row=0,sticky=W, padx =10)
I_Label = Label(root, text='Invoice Path:', bg='#A2B5CD', fg='black',font=('Calibri', 12))
I_Label.grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx =10)

var = StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose Carrier...')
option = OptionMenu(root, var, 'DHL','DPD','DX','Fedex','Geodis','Hermes','WN Direct')
option.config(relief=RAISED, highlightbackground='#A2B5CD')
option.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W, pady = 10)

browser = Button(root, text = 'Browse Invoice...', command=Choose_Path)
browser.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
b1 = Button(root, text='Accept and Close', command = CloseGUI).grid(column=1, sticky=S)
mainloop()

print var.get()
print path
```

Thanks for your help! +1

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

-You're going to have to figure out when to end your root's mainloop. From the moment you call `root.mainloop()`, currently the program will not advcance to the next line (which you don't have, but I assume you will in your final program) until you close the Tk window.

-After the mainloop has ended, you need to have your variable values somewhere. Currently, the `option` object (which is an `OptionMenu` instance) will contain the value if your carrier, so you can just do something like `option.get()`.
The filename is slightly more complicated, because you don't store that somewhere: you return it from `Choose_Path()` but the return value isn't stored anywhere. Probably you're going to have to store this value in a global. (This storing has to happen within `Choose_Path`, e.g. `FileName = askopenfilename()` instead of `return askopenfilename()`).

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response! So i need to add a root.exit() to proceed to the next line of my script?  I have added the root.exit() to the command of the accept and close button.... printing option.get() still doesnt print anything though :/  i have also changed the return statement to what you suggested but am still confused how I access this variable later?

Comment: You may be able to avoid using root.mainloop by using root.update, where needed, instead.  However, I have not experimented with the file dialog and OptionMenu.

Comment: @Luke: actually, I was wrong on the `option.get()` - this should be `var.get()`. You need to store the result of this in some variable later (e.g. add `carrier = var.get()` to the end of your code). I'm not sure where the confusion about the path comes from though. Try adding `path = [None]` to the start of your code, and then `path[0] = askopenfilename()` inside `Choose_Path`. Then, at the end of your code, `path = path[0]` will get you the path. (I use a list to avoid having to declare globals here. Not necessarily optimal.)

Comment: Thankyou acdr. Your soloution may well have worked... however as you and @Terry Jan Reedy have touched on before, I cannot verify that the variables have been stored due to the rest of my scrip not continuing. I have added the simple example    print '1234'    which never runs, even though tkinter has been closed with    command = exit    . Could either of you share some insight on how to exit the root and continue with python code, or use the root.update() function correctly. Many Thanks

Comment: If I do `root.destroy()`, then that ends the mainloop, and any code I have after my `root.mainloop()` is executed.